# Error 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE FUNCTION `remover_acentos` (text_1 text)
RETURNS text

select 
replace(text_1,'áâãäéêëíîÏóöôõúûüÁÂÃÄÉÊËÍÎÏÓÖÔÕÚÛÜçÇ','aaaaeeeiiioooouuuAAAAEEEIIIOOOOUUUcC');
```

The function above is throwing the error below.

```
Error 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a function
```

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: Please (1) use English language (2) provide full code of your function (3) show us how you call it and the sample data

Comment: the code of my function is complete

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't look like it is. You have a draft to create function `remover_acentos` and you are using `replace` function. This is misleading. Translate your description to English and show us what you're trying to achieve with the code providing sample data

Comment: i'm trying replace all the special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the `SELECT` doing there? That's causing the error. Use `RETURN` to return a scalar value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `remover_acentos` (text_1 text)
RETURNS text

RETURN replace(text_1,'áâãäéêëíîÏóöôõúûüÁÂÃÄÉÊËÍÎÏÓÖÔÕÚÛÜçÇ','aaaaeeeiiioooouuuAAAAEEEIIIOOOOUUUcC');
```

But this won't do what you want, I guess. If you want to replace any single occurrence of one of the characters, you'll need more than one `replace()` -- for each character, use one. Like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `remover_acentos` (text_1 text)
RETURNS text
BEGIN
  SET text_1 = replace(text_1,'á','a');
  SET text_1 = replace(text_1,'à','a');
  ...
  RETURN text_1;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION `remover_acentos` (text_1 text)
RETURNS text
BEGIN

select 
replace(text_1,'áâãäéêëíîÏóöôõúûüÁÂÃÄÉÊËÍÎÏÓÖÔÕÚÛÜçÇ','aaaaeeeiiioooouuuAAAAEEEIIIOOOOUUUcC');
 
RETURN text;
END                                                                                                  
                                                                                                          just like that ?